# Clear Duplicate values out off array?

Tags: php, arrays, unique

HI all

Can someone please please help me been trying to suss this for a while now scratching my head.

I am adding links to a SESSION array here is my code.

```
    session_start();
$test = $_GET;
$_SESSION['value'][]=$test;
echo "<pre>";
//print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";


$turn = $_SESSION['value'];

foreach (array_reverse($turn) as $value) { 

$furl = "http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/".urlencode($value['tune_name']);

echo $furl;

}
```

here is the result off my print_r($_SESSION);

```
Array
(
    [attach] => Array
        (
        )

    [backups-2] => true
    [dnb] => true
    [house] => true
    [tech-house] => true
    [uk-garage] => true
    [uk-grime] => true
    [uk-hip-hop] => true
    [uncategorized] => true
    [warehouse] => true
    [active] => 
    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tune_name] => Music/dnb/03 Twerk feat. Yo Majesty (Sub Focus Remix).mp3
                    [tune] => http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music/dnb/03 Twerk feat. Yo Majesty (Sub Focus Remix).mp3
                    [submit] => Listen
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [tune_name] => Music/dnb/Abort_Delta Heavy_192.mp3
                    [tune] => http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music/dnb/Abort_Delta Heavy_192.mp3
                    [submit] => Listen
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [tune_name] => Music/dnb/03 Twerk feat. Yo Majesty (Sub Focus Remix).mp3
                    [tune] => http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music/dnb/03 Twerk feat. Yo Majesty (Sub Focus Remix).mp3
                    [submit] => Listen
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [tune_name] => Music/dnb/21st Century (Feat. Cabbie)_Tantrum Desire_192.mp3
                    [tune] => http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music/dnb/21st Century (Feat. Cabbie)_Tantrum Desire_192.mp3
                    [submit] => Listen
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [tune_name] => Music/dnb/Abort_Delta Heavy_192.mp3
                    [tune] => http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music/dnb/Abort_Delta Heavy_192.mp3
                    [submit] => Listen
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [tune_name] => Music/dnb/03 Twerk feat. Yo Majesty (Sub Focus Remix).mp3
                    [tune] => http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music/dnb/03 Twerk feat. Yo Majesty (Sub Focus Remix).mp3
                    [submit] => Listen
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [tune_name] => Music/dnb/Abort_Delta Heavy_192.mp3
                    [tune] => http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music/dnb/Abort_Delta Heavy_192.mp3
                    [submit] => Listen
                )

        )

)
```

so what i am trying to do is loop through that array and show the link but i dont what any duplicate values.

```
$turn = $_SESSION['value'];

foreach (array_reverse($turn) as $value) { 

$furl = "http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/".urlencode($value['tune_name']);

echo $furl;

}
```

and this is the result i get from the foreach.

```
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2FAbort_Delta+Heavy_192.mp3
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2FAbort_Delta+Heavy_192.mp3
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2F03+Twerk+feat.+Yo+Majesty+%28Sub+Focus+Remix%29.mp3
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2FAbort_Delta+Heavy_192.mp3
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2F21st+Century+%28Feat.+Cabbie%29_Tantrum+Desire_192.mp3
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2F03+Twerk+feat.+Yo+Majesty+%28Sub+Focus+Remix%29.mp3
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2FAbort_Delta+Heavy_192.mp3
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

So annoying i only want it to show.

```
 http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2FAbort_Delta+Heavy_192.mp3
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2F03+Twerk+feat.+Yo+Majesty+%28Sub+Focus+Remix%29.mp3
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2F21st+Century+%28Feat.+Cabbie%29_Tantrum+Desire_192.mp3
```

Because above doesnt have any duplicate values i have tried so much array_unique hasnt worked for me can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an associative array to check if it's already outputted.

```
$outputted = array();
```

Use `$furl` as a key.

```
foreach (array_reverse($turn) as $value) { 

    $furl = "http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/".urlencode($value['tune_name']);

    if (isset($outputted[$furl])) {
        continue;
    }

    echo $furl;

    $outputted[$furl] = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Try this:

```
function filter($val)
{
    static $base=array();
    if(in_array($val,$base))return false;
    $base[]=$val;
    return true;
}
array_filter($arr,"filter");
```

It will remove any duplicate values from the array $arr.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
array_reverse($turn)
```

to

```
array_unique(array_reverse($turn))
```

so it looks like this

```
foreach (array_unique(array_reverse($turn)) as $value) { 
    $furl = "http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/".urlencode($value['tune_name']);
    echo $furl;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for this tried this first but didnt work or ouptut anything

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) it filters out all [duplicated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) values like:

```
$turn = $_SESSION['value'];

foreach (array_unique(array_reverse($turn)) as $value) { 

$furl = "http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/".urlencode($value['tune_name']);

echo $furl;

}
```

result should be:

```
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2FAbort_Delta+Heavy_192.mp3
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2F03+Twerk+feat.+Yo+Majesty+%28Sub+Focus+Remix%29.mp3
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/Music%2Fdnb%2F21st+Century+%28Feat.+Cabbie%29_Tantrum+Desire_192.mp3
```